# Edge IE mode not working as expected in Qmetry

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, qaf

I want to run edge ie mode using qmetry. We are getting wired blank white IE page being opened when we click on login button in our application. Same website works fine when i executed it without qmetry.

standalone code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", Global.WINDOWS_USER_HOME + "\.cache\selenium\IEDriverServer\win64\" + IEversion + "\IEDriverServer.exe");
InternetExplorerOptions iExplorerOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();
iExplorerOptions.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.FORCE_CREATE_PROCESS, true);
iExplorerOptions.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_SWITCHES, "-private");
iExplorerOptions.attachToEdgeChrome();
iExplorerOptions.ignoreZoomSettings();
iExplorerOptions.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
iExplorerOptions.withEdgeExecutablePath("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe");
return new InternetExplorerDriver(new BrowserFactory().setInternetExplorerOptions());`
```

**Code used for Qmetry**

```
String IEversion = downloadWebDriver();
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", Global.WINDOWS_USER_HOME + "\.cache\selenium\IEDriverServer\win64\" + IEversion + "\IEDriverServer.exe");
ConfigurationManager.getBundle().setProperty("iexplorer.additional.capabilities", "{'initialBrowserUrl':'" + Global.IE_INITIAL_BROWSERURL + "','ignoreProtectedModeSettings': true,'ignoreZoomSetting': true,'ie.browserCommandLineSwitches':'-private','ie.edgechromium':true,'ie.edgepath':'C://Program Files (x86)//Microsoft//Edge//Application//msedge.exe','ie.forceCreateProcessApi':true}");
Global.driver.set(new QAFExtendedWebDriver());  
return new QAFExtendedWebDriver();
```

Could you please take a look and let us know what is wrong with QAF 3.1.0?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in `return new QAFExtendedWebDriver();` you need to use constructor with capabilities object `return new QAFExtendedWebDriver(capabilities);`.

Assuming that you have set driver name and driver capabilities, the right way is to use `getDriver()` method from test base in one of the following ways:

```
new WebDriverTestBase().getDriver();
new WebDriverTestCase().getDriver();
(QAFExtendedWebDriver)TestBaseProvider.instance().get().getUiDriver();
```

Easiest way to create capability in json format is to create capability object and print. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
        InternetExplorerOptions iExplorerOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();
        iExplorerOptions.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.FORCE_CREATE_PROCESS, true);
        iExplorerOptions.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_SWITCHES, "-private");
        iExplorerOptions.attachToEdgeChrome();
        iExplorerOptions.ignoreZoomSettings();
        iExplorerOptions.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
        iExplorerOptions.withEdgeExecutablePath("C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft/Edge/Application/msedge.exe");
        
        System.out.println(JSONUtil.toString(iExplorerOptions.asMap()));
}
```

this will print

> {"browserName":"internet explorer","ie.browserCommandLineSwitches":"-private","ie.edgechromium":true,"ie.edgepath":"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft/Edge/Application/msedge.exe","ie.forceCreateProcessApi":true,"ignoreProtectedModeSettings":true,"ignoreZoomSetting":true,"se:ieOptions":{"ie.edgechromium":true,"ie.browserCommandLineSwitches":"-private","ie.forceCreateProcessApi":true,"ignoreZoomSetting":true,"ie.edgepath":"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft/Edge/Application/msedge.exe","ignoreProtectedModeSettings":true}}

if you have used driver name as `iexplorer` set capability for edge driver from above reference.

```
driver.name=iexplorerDriver
iexplorer.additional.capabilities={"browserName":"internet explorer","ie.browserCommandLineSwitches":"-private","ie.edgechromium":true,"ie.edgepath":"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft/Edge/Application/msedge.exe","ie.forceCreateProcessApi":true,"ignoreProtectedModeSettings":true,"ignoreZoomSetting":true,"se:ieOptions":{"ie.edgechromium":true,"ie.browserCommandLineSwitches":"-private","ie.forceCreateProcessApi":true,"ignoreZoomSetting":true,"ie.edgepath":"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft/Edge/Application/msedge.exe","ignoreProtectedModeSettings":true}}
```